# done() vs return done()

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I was reading the docs for passport and I noticed that with `serialize()` and `deserialize()` `done()` is called with out being returned.

However when setting up a new strategy using `passport.use()` in the callback function `return done()` is used.

Is this something that needs to be understood or just copied from the docs?

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/

From the docs:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: The return value of serialize/deserialize is discarded, so you don't need to return anything. `done()` also returns nothing.

Comment: note that you are not returning done() you are returning the result of calling done()

Comment: @DanPantry the fact that a `return` statement ends function execution immediately is often important, whether or not the returned value is interesting and/or will be used by a caller.

Comment: @Dan ... in the docs they are using `return done()` in `passport.use()`.  Are you saying that the return statement is not needed?

Comment: @tex ... are you saying they are using return in the example I posted above for flow control and not b.c. it actually returns anything?

Comment: @j.a. That is exactly correct - they are using `return` for flow control. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @tex sure; when i answered this question the code sample in question was not present :)

Comment: @DanPantry It wasn't present when I wrote my first comment or the first version of my answer, either :)

Comment: As a matter of programming style I think that `return done()` is not so great.  Use an `if \ else`.  Isn't this exactly why the language has `if / else` ?  It is like they have decided that `if \ else` is no longer part of the language ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return done()` will cause the function to stop executing immediately. This means that any other lines of code after that line inside the function will be ignored and not evaluated.

`done()` not preceded by `return`, however, will not cause the function to stop executing. This means that any other lines of code after that line inside the function will be evaluated.

If you take a look at this `passport.use()` example (from the Passport docs), you'll see there is reachable code after the first three `return done()` statements, and you would want the function to exit immediately as soon as `done()` is called the first time to make sure none of the following instructions are evaluated:

```js
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); } 
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      // The following line is the success case. We do not want to execute it
      // if there was an error, a falsy user or a user without a valid 
      // password. If we removed the return keywords from the previous lines
      // of code, the success case would be triggered every time this
      // function was called
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Here I've added two executable snippets to illustrate the difference between `done()` and `return done(). The snippets are otherwise identical.

`done()` without `return`:

```js
const done = console.log

const assessThreatLevel = threatLevel => {
  if (threatLevel === 'all good') done('relax :)')
  done('launch the missiles!')
}

assessThreatLevel('all good')
```

`return done():

```js
const done = console.log

const assessThreatLevel = threatLevel => {
  if (threatLevel === 'all good') return done('relax :)')
  done('launch the missiles!')
}

assessThreatLevel('all good')
```

As an aside, I have taken to using `return done()` in most situations for consistency. As far as I'm aware, there's no drawback to using it. It can help you avoid bugs, and the `return` statement serves as a guarantee and a good visual reminder that the function will exit immediately after that statement is evaluated.

Comment: seems like this is what if/else statements were created for.  I guess it is that style you prefer.

Comment: It's also important to note that if `done` is actually a promise, there is even more meaning to returning `done` or not.